# How to Store result of a HAS_MANY RELATION database query in yii?

Tags: php, yii

PLEASE HELP....I AM A NEWBIE

I have 2 tables **PAGE** and **COMMENT.**

**Page** table has columns

```
$id
$user_id 
$content
```

**Comment** table has columns

```
$id
$user_id
$page_id
$date_entered

$comment      **The comment column consist of an array of comments as one user can have many comments**
```

In the Page model the relation in the relation() is defined as

```
return array(
    'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'page_id')
)
```

Now in the PageControllor.php,I have defined this query in the actionView()

```
$page = Page::model()->with('user','comments')->findByPk($id);
```

Now my question is

how can i get the result of this query in **$result** so that i could pass it to the view page as

```
$this->render('view',array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id),'result'=>$result))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exactly answer your question, all you have to do is,

```
$this->render('view',array(
    'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    'result'=>$page
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You havent defined what "this query" is that you want to assign to result.

However, if all you want is to get a list of all the comments associated with a page, all you need to do is this:

```
foreach($page->comments as $comment){
    ....
}
```

when calling `$this->render` do the following:

```
$this->render('view', array('page'=>$page);
```

when you assign `$page` you don't actually need the with method - thats only if you are going to be querying on those fields. So This will suffice:

```
$page = Page::model()->findByPk($id)
```

Comment: I used this extension to fix all my problems in M to M relations 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-manymanyactiverecord/

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you sir...this extension is really helpful and makes the task much more easier...thanks a lot for letting me know about it.. :)